# nexus 10 tablet characters illegible

Tags: fonts, samsung-nexus-10

I've installed two apps on my Nexus 10 tablet and the characters show up as boxes with x's through them as shown below. i'be contacted the developers of the Rosetta Stone app to no avail.

I'm in android 4.3. any suggestions as to settings or installations that can solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a font/localization issue: Most likely the apps in question want to use a font which is not available on your device, and the font substituted by the system does not match the characters used. You could use `adb logcat` to check for related errors.

Comment: It's not saying much for the quality of Rosetta if it struggles to understand a foreign language!

Comment: @Izzy thanks, so basically you're telling me I need to plug in the device and run the program from an editor like Eclipse or IntelliJ to fix this?? yikes,I think this is more of a Nexus problem, since it happened on the same device to two foreign language programs?

Comment: Not exactly. Plug in the device, yes. Eclipse, not necessarily: You can run `adb logcat` from command line. I do that all the time. Recommendation: use `adb logcat -f <filename>` to write the log to a file to investigate, output can be quite long. See also: [`adb` help](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), [`logcat` help](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html), [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575). // And it's a "foreign language apps problem with your Nexus", yes :)